# how to Search Result Record Paging

Tags: php, search, paging

This code is working fine for searching  with **POST method**, how to pagination search results?

I have attach images. First image searching with this field:

[image: First image searching with this field]

Searching result in which I want paging:

[image: Searching result in which want paging]

```
<? php
include('connection.php');
    if (isset($_POST['search'])) {


        $fields = array('EJAMAATID', 'GNAME', 'MOBNO', 'EMAILID', 'DNNO', 'GCNTRYID', 'PINCODE', 'GCITYID', 'DNTYPE');`search field`

        $conditions = array();

        foreach($fields as $field) {

            if (isset($_POST[$field]) && $_POST[$field] != '') {

                $conditions[] = "`$field` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$field]). "%'";`condition`
            }
        }


        $query = "SELECT * FROM donation ";   
        $orderby = "ORDER BY DNDATE desc";
        $datebetween = "AND DNDATE >='$start' AND DNDATE<='$end'";

        if (count($conditions) > 0) {

$yakin5 = implode(' AND ', $conditions);
$query. = "WHERE ".$yakin5.$datebetween.$orderby; 
        }

    }
    $jo = (isset($query)) ? $query : '';

    $don4 = mysql_query($jo);
    while ($roww = mysql_fetch_array($don4)) {

        }
    ?>
```

Comment: And your question is...

Comment: Search/pagination is usually done in a `GET` method. Convert it to that first (your form and your search code). Then you will need to count your results using `COUNT(*)` so you can work out how many page links to render. Finally each of them will need a query string containing your search parameters and also a page number. You can use `LIMIT` in MySQL to get a section of results, look it up in a search engine.

Comment: searching is not working with GET method if you have any idea of Working of GET method please help regarding this issue with sample code if possible